# C# - Can't figure out how to read custom objects to file, add new custom objects, and write new set to overwritten file

Tags: c#, datetime, file-io, format, overwrite

I understand that's probably confusing, so let me explain. I'm trying to make a program that mimics a calendar program, and it almost works. I'm just having difficulty with writing to an output file. I have a custom object `Event` that I can write to a file, and I can read strings from a file and create new objects based off that information. However, I'm having difficulty in trying to add new `Events` to old ones and then write all that information back to the file, while also overwriting the last version of the file. I included comments in my program, so hopefully that makes it a little clearer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

// Date: 4/24/17

// Purpose (according to Reddit spec)
/* create a program that will allow you to enter events organizable by hour. There must be menu options of some form, and you must be 
 * able to easily edit, add, and delete events without directly changing the source code.
 * (note that by menu i dont necessarily mean gui. as long as you can easily access the different options and receive prompts and 
 * instructions telling you how to use the program, it will probably be fine) */

namespace ChallengeOneIntermediate
{
   class Event
   {
      string eventName;
      DateTime eventDay;
      DateTime eventTime;

      public string EventName
      {
         get { return eventName; }
         set { eventName = value; }
      }

      public DateTime EventDay
      {
         get { return eventDay; }
         set { eventDay = value; }
      }

      public DateTime EventTime
      {
         get { return eventTime; }
         set { eventTime = value; }
      }

      public Event(string name, DateTime day, DateTime time)
      {
         eventName = name;
         eventDay = day;
         eventTime = time;
      }
   }

   class Program
   {
      public static List<string> ADD_CHOICES = new List<string> { "1", "1.", "add", "add event", "1 add event", "1. add event", 
                                                                 "1.add event", "1addevent", "1add event", "1.add event",
                                                                 "1 addevent", "1. addevent", "1add", "1.add", "1 add", "1. add" };

      public static List<string> DEL_CHOICES = new List<string> { "2", "2.", "delete", "delete event", "2 delete event", 
                                                                 "2. delete event", "2deleteevent", "2.deleteevent", "2delete event", 
                                                                 "2.delete event", "2 deleteevent", "2. deleteevent", "2delete",
                                                                 "2.delete", "2 delete", "2. delete" };

      public static List<string> EDIT_CHOICES = new List<string> { "3", "3.", "edit", "edit event", "3 edit event", "3. edit event",
                                                                  "3editevent", "3.editevent", "3edit event", "3.edit event",
                                                                  "3 editevent", "3. editevent", "3edit", "3.edit", "3 edit",
                                                                  "3. edit" };

      public static List<string> VIEW_CHOICES = new List<string> { "4", "4.", "view", "calendar", "viewcalendar", "view calendar",
                                                                  "4.view", "4. view", "4.calendar", "4. calendar",
                                                                  "4.viewcalendar", "4.view calendar", "4. viewcalendar",
                                                                  "4. view calendar", "4viewcalendar", "4view calendar",
                                                                  "4 viewcalendar", "4 view calendar" };

      public static List<string> EXIT_CHOICES = new List<string> { "5", "5.", "exit", "5 exit", "5. exit", "5exit", "5.exit" };

      public static List<Event> EVENT_CALENDAR = new List<Event>();

      public static string PATH = @"G:\Daily Programmer\C#\Intermediate\Challenge #1\calendar.txt";

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         int menuChoice;

         while (true)
         {
            menuChoice = Menu();

            if (menuChoice == 1)
               AddEvent();
            else if (menuChoice == 2)
               DeleteEvent();
            else if (menuChoice == 3)
               EditEvent();
            else if (menuChoice == 4)
               ViewCalendar();
            else if (menuChoice == 5)
               break;
            else
               Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that's not a valid choice.\n");
         }

         // No point in writing to the file if there's nothing in EVENT_CALENDAR to write
         if (EVENT_CALENDAR.Count > 0)
            WriteToFile();

         Console.ReadLine();
      }

      static void AddEvent()
      {
         DateTime newDate, newTime;
         string eventName, eventDate, eventTime;

         Console.Write("Enter the name of your event, or 'exit' to go back to the menu: ");
         eventName = Console.ReadLine();

         if (EXIT_CHOICES.Contains(eventName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;

         Console.Write("Enter the date of your event in the format MM/DD/YYYY: ");
         eventDate = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("Enter the time of your event in the format HH:MM AM/PM: ");
         eventTime = Console.ReadLine();

         try
         {
            DateTime.TryParse(eventDate, out newDate);
            DateTime.TryParse(eventTime, out newTime);
            Event newCalendarEvent = new Event(eventName, newDate, newTime);
            EVENT_CALENDAR.Add(newCalendarEvent);

            // Uses LINQ to sort by day, then by time
            EVENT_CALENDAR = EVENT_CALENDAR.OrderBy(x => x.EventDay).ThenBy(x => x.EventTime).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Event: " + eventName + " added successfully!");
         }
         catch (FormatException fe)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(fe.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you didn't enter the date and time in the right format. Please try again.");
         }
      }

      static void DeleteEvent()
      {
         string userInput;
         int num = 1, eventToDelete;

         // Easiest way I could think of in a non-visual format to identify which event the user is trying to delete
         foreach (Event eachEvent in EVENT_CALENDAR)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(num + ". " + eachEvent.EventName + ", {0:MM/dd/yyyy} @ {1:hh:mm tt}", 
                              eachEvent.EventDay, eachEvent.EventTime);
            num++;
         }

         Console.WriteLine();

         Console.Write("Enter the number of the event you want to delete, or 'exit' to go back to the menu: ");
         userInput = Console.ReadLine();

         if (EXIT_CHOICES.Contains(userInput, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;
         else
         {
            Int32.TryParse(userInput, out eventToDelete);

            if (eventToDelete != 0 && (eventToDelete < 1 || eventToDelete > EVENT_CALENDAR.Count))
               while (eventToDelete < 1 || eventToDelete > EVENT_CALENDAR.Count)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid choice. Please enter another number: ");
                  eventToDelete = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
               }
         }

         EVENT_CALENDAR.RemoveAt(eventToDelete - 1);

         // No need to re-sort EVENT_CALENDAR because order is maintained

         Console.WriteLine("Event deleted successfully!");
      }

      static void EditEvent()
      {
         DateTime newDate, newTime;
         string eventName, eventDate, eventTime, userInput;
         int num = 1, eventToEdit;

         // Including the sort here too because for some reason it wasn't appropriately sorting events added with blank names
         // Uses LINQ to sort by day, then by time
         EVENT_CALENDAR = EVENT_CALENDAR.OrderBy(x => x.EventDay).ThenBy(x => x.EventTime).ToList();

         foreach (Event eachEvent in EVENT_CALENDAR)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(num + ". " + eachEvent.EventName + ", {0:MM/dd/yyyy} @ {1:hh:mm tt}",
                              eachEvent.EventDay, eachEvent.EventTime);
            num++;
         }

         Console.WriteLine();

         Console.Write("Enter the number of the event you'd like to edit, or 'exit' to return to the menu: ");
         userInput = Console.ReadLine();

         if (EXIT_CHOICES.Contains(userInput, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;
         else
         {
            Int32.TryParse(userInput, out eventToEdit);

            if (eventToEdit != 0 && (eventToEdit < 1 || eventToEdit > EVENT_CALENDAR.Count))
               while (eventToEdit < 1 || eventToEdit > EVENT_CALENDAR.Count)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid choice. Please enter another number: ");
                  eventToEdit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
               }
         }

         Console.Write("What is the new name of the event? ");
         eventName = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("Enter the new date of your event in the format MM/DD/YYYY: ");
         eventDate = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.Write("Enter the new time of your event in the format HH:MM AM/PM: ");
         eventTime = Console.ReadLine();

         try
         {
            // eventToEdit acts as index + 1 here, so I have to subtract 1 to get the right index internally
            EVENT_CALENDAR[eventToEdit - 1].EventName = eventName;

            DateTime.TryParse(eventDate, out newDate);
            EVENT_CALENDAR[eventToEdit - 1].EventDay = newDate;

            DateTime.TryParse(eventTime, out newTime);
            EVENT_CALENDAR[eventToEdit - 1].EventTime = newTime;

            // Uses LINQ to order by day, then by time
            EVENT_CALENDAR = EVENT_CALENDAR.OrderBy(x => x.EventDay).ThenBy(x => x.EventTime).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Event: " + eventName + " edited successfully!");
         }
         catch (FormatException fe)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(fe.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you didn't enter the date and time in the right format. Please try again.");
         }
      }

      static int IntMenuChoice(string stringMenuChoice)
      {
         if (ADD_CHOICES.Contains(stringMenuChoice, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return 1;
         else if (DEL_CHOICES.Contains(stringMenuChoice, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return 2;
         else if (EDIT_CHOICES.Contains(stringMenuChoice, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return 3;
         else if (VIEW_CHOICES.Contains(stringMenuChoice, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return 4;
         else if (EXIT_CHOICES.Contains(stringMenuChoice, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return 5;
         else
            return -1;
      }

      static int Menu()
      {
         string strChoice;
         int intChoice;

         Console.WriteLine();

         Console.WriteLine("-- Options --\n");
         Console.WriteLine("1. Add event\n");
         Console.WriteLine("2. Delete event\n");
         Console.WriteLine("3. Edit event\n");
         Console.WriteLine("4. View calendar\n");
         Console.WriteLine("5. Exit\n");
         Console.Write("Choice: ");
         strChoice = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.WriteLine();

         intChoice = IntMenuChoice(strChoice);

         return intChoice;
      }

      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886945/reading-a-text-file-and-inserting-information-into-a-new-object
      /* The purpose of this function is to try and merge old sessions of a user's calendar with a new session.
       * It's unlikely the user has this program running all the time, and what's the point of having a calendar that only stores
       * events on a session-to-session basis?
       * What I'm attempting to do here is read events from the existing file, create a new list of Event objects based on
       * the fields stored in each line by splitting on spaces, and then assign that sorted list to EVENT_CALENDAR.
       * It seems to work locally (I tested by running a foreach() loop on EVENT_CALENDAR), but not in WriteToFile(). */
      static void SortExistingFile()
      {
         List<Event> existingDates = new List<Event>();
         DateTime existDate, existTime;

         foreach(string fileLine in File.ReadLines(PATH))
         {
            // Split() has to split on characters, not strings, so single quotes
            string[] fields = fileLine.Split(' ');
            DateTime.TryParse(fields[1], out existDate);
            DateTime.TryParse(fields[2], out existTime);
            existingDates.Add(new Event(fields[0], existDate, existTime));
         }

         // Orders all the events read from the file
         existingDates = existingDates.OrderBy(x => x.EventDay).ThenBy(x => x.EventTime).ToList();

         /* I decided to clear the old calendar and indivudally re-write events to it because I wasn't sure
          * if trying to do assignment (ex. EVENT_CALENDAR = existingDates) would only work locally and not
          * maintain its state after the function exits */
         EVENT_CALENDAR.Clear();

         foreach(Event oldEvent in existingDates)
            EVENT_CALENDAR.Add(oldEvent);
      }

      static void ViewCalendar()
      {
         int num = 1;

         if (EVENT_CALENDAR.Count == 0)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("There's nothing in the calendar!");
            return;
         }

         foreach (Event eachEvent in EVENT_CALENDAR)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(num + ". " + eachEvent.EventName + ", {0:MM/dd/yyyy} @ {1:hh:mm tt}",
                              eachEvent.EventDay, eachEvent.EventTime);
            num++;
         }
      }

      static void WriteToFile()
      {
         // I know that this probably hurts performance because then the file's being written to 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n times
         // I wasn't sure of another way I could write Event objects to a file in human-readable format
         try
         {
            foreach(Event eachEvent in EVENT_CALENDAR)
            {
               if (File.Exists(PATH))
               {
                  // I append all the new events to the existing events in the file
                  File.AppendAllText(PATH, String.Format("{0} {1:MM/dd/yyyy} {2:hh:mm tt}" + Environment.NewLine, eachEvent.EventName,
                                       eachEvent.EventDay, eachEvent.EventTime));
               }
               else
               {
                  FileStream myFile = File.Create(PATH);
                  myFile.Close();
                  File.WriteAllText(PATH, String.Format("{0} {1:MM/dd/yyyy} {2:hh:mm tt}" + Environment.NewLine, eachEvent.EventName,
                                    eachEvent.EventDay, eachEvent.EventTime));
               }
            }
         }
         catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException\n");
            Console.WriteLine(ane.Message);
         }
         catch (IOException ioe)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("IOException\n");
            Console.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
         }
         catch (ArgumentException ae)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentException\n");
            Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception\n");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
         }

         // Here's where I sort all the existing events that merged with the new events and store them in EVENT_CALENDAR
         SortExistingFile();
         string allEvents = String.Empty;

         // This is what I can't get to work
         /* My intent here was to store everything in one massive string.
          * Why do this? I want to overwrite the file each time the program closes so all events are in order.
          * I couldn't get File.Copy(PATH, PATH, true) to work.
          * WriteAllText() does what I want, but it wouldn't work in a foreach() loop because it would always just overwrite
          * the previous event, so only the most recent event in the calendar would be stored. */
         foreach(Event eachEvent in EVENT_CALENDAR)
         {
            allEvents += eachEvent.EventName + " " + String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", eachEvent.EventDay.ToString()) +
                         " " + String.Format("{0:hh:mm tt", eachEvent.EventTime.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
         }

         // If the above code worked, then I could do this and all the events would be stored in the calendar file.
         File.WriteAllText(PATH, allEvents);
      }
   }
}
```

**Clarity Edit:** I couldn't get the Copy to work, as I was throwing an error where I was trying to write to the file which was already open (I believe this is because I was trying to copy from PATH to PATH). I came up with the idea of writing everything to one string with newlines, and then storing that in a file. However, I'm getting an error that states the DateTime object is invalid, despite that it was valid earlier when the user entered it and I converted it to a DateTime object. The WriteAllText works fine. I just wouldn't be able to use it in a foreach loop because calling WriteAllText on every iteration of the loop would overwrite the last event written in the current session.

I know this isn't an ideal program to make exclusively as a Console application, but it works almost exactly as intended, save for this one aspect of reading from a file and overwriting back to the same file. This is a challenge from DailyProgrammer, and I decided to enhance it a little bit by adding the ability to write the calendar to a file.

**NullReferenceException problem, but why?**
Thanks to JohnG, I was able to rewrite `SortExistingFile()` function to read correctly, and rewrote my `WriteToFile()` function to overwrite correctly. However, now I'm getting a NullReferenceException on `eventFieldArray` in `SortExistingFile()` even though I've tried initializing it with different values. I don't know what's causing it. Here's the revised function:

```
static void SortExistingFile()
      {
         List<Event> existingDates = new List<Event>();
         DateTime existDateTime;
         string readLine;
         string[] eventFieldArray = null;
         long fileLength = new FileInfo(PATH).Length;

         // Check if file has any contents so there's no attempt to read the file when it doesn't contain anything
         if (fileLength == 0)
            return;
         else
         {
            try
            {
               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PATH))
               {
                  while (fileLength > 0)
                  {
                     readLine = sr.ReadLine();
                     eventFieldArray = readLine.Split(',');
                     DateTime.TryParse(eventFieldArray[1], out existDateTime);
                     existingDates.Add(new Event(eventFieldArray[0], existDateTime));

                     fileLength--;
                  }
               }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
               Console.ReadLine();
            }
         }

         EVENT_CALENDAR = existingDates.OrderBy(x => x.EventDateTime).ToList();
      }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the problem is? Is it the Copy, or the WriteAllText? What does not work in your code?

Comment: You have dumped fairly large amount of code without explaining what you are trying to achieve. You cannot expect people to read comments in your code, understand the whole code and provide a solution.  Be specific.

Comment: `// This is what I can't get to work
         /* My intent here was to store everything in one massive string.
          * Why do this? I want to overwrite the file each time the program closes so all events are in order.
          * I couldn't get File.Copy(PATH, PATH, true) to work.
          * WriteAllText() does what I want, but it wouldn't work in a foreach() loop because it would always just overwrite
          * the previous event, so only the most recent event in the calendar would be stored. */`

Comment: I am curious why you are choosing to write this as a console application. In the comments, it appears to indicate that you could use a form(s) (GUI) for this. If I understand the problem correctly, managing these events is certainly something you can do from the console as you are. However, have you considered what the “User” would prefer? I am confident the user would prefer a form(s) and IMHO easier to code for you.

Comment: Console applications are not very user friendly, especially when it comes to a date. The user can type in the date as needed… THEN you will have to check if the user typed in a VALID date and if it is invalid, you have to prompt the user to re-type it. I would think from both perspectives as the coder OR the user a `DateTimePicker` on a form would not only be more intuitive and easier to use for the user but the main bonus is by using this `DateTimePicker` control it will involve a lot less coding for you since the control will only allow valid dates.

Comment: @Natrium I couldn't get the Copy to work, as I was throwing an error where I was trying to write to the file which was already open (I believe this is because I was trying to copy from PATH to PATH). I came up with the idea of writing everything to one string with newlines, and then storing that in a file. However, I'm getting an error that states the DateTime object is invalid, despite that it was valid earlier when the user entered it and I converted it to a DateTime object.

The WriteAllText works fine. I just wouldn't be able to use it in a foreach loop.

Comment: @JohnG I made this a console application because I haven't learned GUI programming yet, and only recently started learning C#. I went to DailyProgrammer on Reddit to try and build up my understanding of the language after I got an intermediate understanding of the syntax. I know it's not ideal, but save for reading existing events from and writing back to the file, the program does work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are never reading IN the data you save. I am aware you want to save this data by writing it to a file… but it is useless unless you read it back in.

In the example you have, when the program starts… it should go and look for the file `calander.txt` and if found read in the existing events to allow the user to `view/edit/delete` these already existing events. When you read these events in, you can put them in a List as you are and you can add, edit and delete events from this list as you already are. When the user adds, deletes or updates an event you update this event in the list, then you simply have to write the WHOLE list to the file and overwrite the previous version. If you never read the data back in, then there is no reason to save it in the first place.

If you read the whole "calendar.txt" file into a List of Event objects, then additions, changes or deletions made to the List will contain the updated data, So… given this, each time an event is added, deleted or changed, you simply write the List of UPDATED Event objects to the file. No need to check to see if it exists, if it does not exist then create a new file, if it does exist, then simply overwrite it. Then when you run the program again later, it will read in the previous changes. This appears to be what you want to do.

Below is a simple write method that takes a List of Event objects and a string filename to write the list to the file. After this file is written then you should change your code to READ this file into a list of Event objects when the program starts. I hope this makes sense.

The code below uses a `StreamWriter` and should work as well. The other change I made is that the `Event` class has two `DataTime` objects… one for the date and another for the time… this is unnecessary because one `DateTime` object can and should hold both the date and the time of the event. The last change is it appears the code is using spaces “ “ as a delimiter for the event name and event date time in the file. I changed this to have a comma “,” delimiter so you can have event names with spaces. Hope this helps.

```
private void WriteToFile(List<Event> allEvents, string filepath) {
  try {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath)) {
      foreach (Event curEvent in allEvents) {
         sw.WriteLine(curEvent.EventName + "," + curEvent.EventDateTime.ToString());
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Write Error: " + e.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

**Edit: Sort using the IComparable interface...**

Looking at your sort method… there may be an easier way to sort the list by implementing the `IComparable<Event>` interface for the `Events` class like below. The `CompareTo` will sort two `Event` objects based on event name, then event date if the event names are the same.

To implement this... place the interface in the `Event` signature like below:

```
public class Event : IComparable<Event> {
```

After, you add the `IComparable<Event>` interface… the compiler will complain that the method below `CompareTo` has not been implemented. Add the `CompareTo` method to fix that.

```
public int CompareTo(Event other) {
  int result = this.eventName.CompareTo(other.eventName);
  if (result == 0) {
    return this.eventDateTime.CompareTo(other.eventDateTime);
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
```

After that, you can sort the List of Event objects like below:

```
EVENT_CALENDAR.Sort();
```

The call above will use the `CompareTo` method in the `Event` class to sort the list. IMHO much easier than the `SortExistingFile()` method.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I rewrote my SortExistingFile() function and ran it at the beginning of the program, so now it reads and writes as intended. However, I'm now having an issue in that function that throws a NullReferenceException on `eventFieldArray` even though I've tried initializing it several different ways. The thing is, the program still works correctly after it throws the exception. I'm not sure why it's throwing the exception. I'll add the new code as an edit to my original issue.

Comment: @neutralapplause... I edited my answer and added a possibly easier way to sort the list of event objects.

Answer (score 0):

I red a bit of the code, and I find the question a bit confusing. I couldn't find a point in your code where you load some sort of Model of the data from your text file. Thus, the first thing that comes to my mind is that your approach is wrong.

First of all, you should be aware that such a program should be backed by a database (even [SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)), which would allow you to read events efficiently, a text file is not the ideal approach in this case, especially if/when there will be many events.

If you want to proceed with a text file, my advice would be the following:

1. Create a new class for your calendar events (ex: `CalEvent`), which then can be used in a `List<CalEvent>` to hold your entire calendar.
2. Serialize the `List<CalEvent>` to a Json Text file, using something like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), to store it on a drive.
3. Deserialize the Json Text file and get your `List<CalEvent>` back.

You then could, for example, use LINQ to search for events inside the `List<CalEvent>` like this:

```
List<CalEvent> calEvents = readJsonFileOutput();
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime twodays = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
IEnumerable<CalEvent> eventsInTheNextTwoDays = calEvents.Where(e => e.DateAndTime >= now && e.DateAndTime <= twodays).ToList();
```

If you absolutely need to store these events, in a sorted fashion, in your text file, you could use `calEvents.OrderBy(e => e.DateAndTime)`. Obviously all this code is just an example.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I know I should use a database, but I'm not intending this for any sort of use beyond proving to myself that I could accomplish the task I found at DailyProgrammer. I was expecting that I'd be the only one ever looking at this program, but I ran into this problem right as I was about to finish up and I couldn't figure out how to solve it. Reading and writing DateTime events from a plain text file was enough for me to be satisfied with completing the task, as everything else works according to the spec.

Comment: @neutralapplause, that's perfectly fine of course. I'm glad you got it sorted thanks to the other answer. :)